# Input type is not working properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, window-soft-input-mode

I have certain number of edittexts in my activity and I specified each edittext with `input type :"number"` In order to show the keyboard only with numbers. when I click on the edittext initially it shows the keyboard with number after a fraction of second it changed to text keyboard.so I cannot types numbers directly.

Even though I've given 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` 
this to my activity.
I don't know the reason why it is changed like that,

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/editText1"
  android:layout_width="200dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="@color/black"
  android:textSize="30dp"
  android:layout_weight="25"
  android:textAlignment="center"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:inputType="numberDecimal"
       />
```

Thank you All for given response to my question I rectified the problem, when I removed these lines`"android:textColor="@color/black"`  `android:textSize="30dp"`  `android:textAlignment="center"` from my code keyboard worked properly Once again thank you All

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem. Use in build.gradle:
`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'`
instead of
`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'`
and
`android:inputType="number"` will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
android:inputType="phone"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

For the EditText if we specify,

```
android:inputType="number"
```

only numbers can be got. But if you use,

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

along with the numbers it can accept special characters like ;,/". etc.

refer this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits

Answer (score 1):

Use "number" format :

```
android:inputType="number"
```

or Define the set you want to use (If using this avoid using `inputType`):

```
android:digits="0123456789"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **digits** in your **EditText** like this to get input from keyboard only with numbers

> android:digits="0123456789"

Comment: Thanks for your reply,It is suddenly gets changed to text keyboard, Even though I specify your code.

Comment: Can you provide the name of device manufacture on which you are testing?

Comment: I'm just checking in android emulator

Comment: give it a test on any android device and let me know if the issue is still not resolved

Comment: I checked with my tablet it is be the same.

Comment: i wonder why this happens with you. i have tested the same code many times and it works perfectly.

Comment: when I removed these lines"android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="30dp" android:textAlignment="center" from my code keyboard worked properly

Comment: @lakshmi Prefer giving text sizes using **sp** instead of **dp** . If my answer helps you upto some extent please accept it as answer and upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,
(if you need dot and comma) otherwise remove it..

```
 <EditText
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="0123456789.," />
```